# How to encourage new users to mark the correct answer?

Tags: discussion

Most of the times new users do not mark the correct answer, even if they solved the issues.

If I answered the question, I feel guilty about asking them to mark the correct answer in a comment.

Is there any **decent** way to inform them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I second kiamlaluno's suggestion, and shall make use of it myself.

I also want to add my add two cents to the suggestion: I think the suggestion should state what grace period to give the user *before* one start nagging him by leaving a comment.  Personally, I think at least 48 hours is appropriate.  (I usually wait 48 hours before marking the correct answer, because I believe marking it too early may discourage others from answering.)

It will also suggest a slightly longer "tutorial" on accepting an answer (or not):

> If one of the answers helped you, you can accept it. To accept an answer, you click the check mark (✓) that is placed to the left of the answer. In that way, other users will see what answer helped you most, and the users who answer will see that you've already found a solution.  If none of the answers helped you, you should edit your question and explain why none of the answers solved your problem.

It would also be helpful if SE provided a link ("unaccepted") to  questions with one or more answers, but none accepted.

In closing, I would like to say that I find myself more disposed towards upvoting correct answers if there are no "correct" mark for any of the answers after 48 hours and also no comment from the OP explaining why he/she's unable to accept an answer.  Looking at the upvoting patterns, I suspect that I'm not the only one doing this. This means that in terms of rep. points, good citizens may actually come out ahead by *not* having their correct answer accepted.

Comment: However, here's interesting one: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74634/how-can-programatically-configure-my-site - user declines to mark best answer because "they all contribute something". (Looking at the votes, it is also obvious that he hasn't upvoted Alfred A. or beth at the time of writing).  Oh well, some people are just stingy I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Accepting answers is not obligatory. That is one of the reasons why the indicator of percentage of the accepted answers is not anymore shown.

That said, if you want to guide a new user who doesn't seem to understand answers can be accepted, you can leave a comment. I would rather follow these points:

- Write the comment for the question
- Avoid leaving multiple comments for the same user
- Avoid leaving the comment when the answer that would be accepted is yours, or there are chances it is yours

A simple comment similar to "If one the answers helped you, you can accept it. In that way, other users will see what helped you more, and the users who answer will see you already found a solution." would be sufficient.

Comment: I usually break 3rd point when OP says my answer helped him and solved his problem, or adds "solved" to question title, but at the same time does not accept. when it happens, I'm commenting that he can tick accepted mark or, if my answer was only a clue, not solution, post and accept answer to his own question.